# SMTP server to send emails

Tags: .net, iis-7, smtp

I have a dedicated windows server with runs iis 6.0 as smtp server and i use .net to send emails. 
I run a blogging website, it has a comment section, when anyone leaves a comment i want to send emails to whoever left a comment on that blog. Some blogs have over 100 suscribers.

I been sending them email in a loop by using "to" field for every subscriber.

My question is, whats the best way of doing it? I dont want to be flaged as spam nor overload the mail server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 100 or even 10,000 subscribers, you will not overload the email server.  Sending a separate email with the recipient in the To: field is the way to go.  If you include multiple recipients as To: or Cc:, they will see each other's email address which violates privacy.  If you include multiple recipients in Bcc: that is a strong indicator to an anti-spam system that the incoming email may not be legitimate.

Not being flagged as spam is a complex subject.

The first, most important rule is to make sure that the people receiving the email know it is an email they signed up for.  Being clear in the subject line goes a long way, e.g.:

> Your comment on MyBlog.com

Beyond that, some things to consider include:

- Ensure that you have a [reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) pointer for your sending domain.
- Consider implementing [Domain Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail).
- Have a look at [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) to understand the ecosystem you are working in.

An alternative is to use a service like [Amazon's Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/).  They provide a robust infrastructure and manage many key aspects of deliverability for you.  They provide a free usage tier up to 2000 emails/day.

**UPDATE**

Regarding whether or not bcc can trigger spam, here's a selection of the google results from *does bcc trigger spam*

> If you put lots and lots of names in the Bcc field, the email may be marked as spam.

http://www.airsquare.com/support/email-marketing/prevent-your-emails-going-to-spam.cfm

> It is better to send an individual message to each recipient, rather than using multiple addresses in the BCC field because many spam filters (and many ISP's) automatically flag multiple recipients as spam.

http://www.xequte.com/support/maillistking/spamissues.html

> Putting multiple addressees in the BCC field was a trick used early by spammers so many spam filters are set up to recognize emails with multiple BCC recipients as spam.

http://releaseit.pwrnewmedia.com/?p=33

Comment: Ok great. My iis is hosting like 10 websites... Now do i need to setup reverse dns for all domains? To setup reverse dns i guess i have to ask my hosting company. Also i am using iis virtual mail server, can i use that as is or should i create virtual sites in smtp server for every domain?

Comment: Also my 10 websites have their own IP's however smtp server is runing on its own wan ip, so in this case whats the best practice to setup reverse dns. Should i create one generic reverse dns for server ip only?

Comment: You point reverse DNS to whatever your DNS MX record resolves to for the domain.  Often but not always that would be mail.yourdomain.com or smtp.yourdomain.com.  You need to setup reverse DNS for each MX record you send email from.  If your hosting company isn't flexible enough to handle that (they should be in this day and age) you can consider a service like http://aws.amazon.com/ses/.  SES is free up to 2000 emails/day, and inexpensive after that.  They manage many aspects of deliverability for you.

Comment: -1 `Bcc:` is not at all a good spam indicator.  Every self-respecting mailing list uses this mechanism.  By contrast, sending hundreds of identical messages which only differ by the `To:` header is in fact a spam indicator.

Comment: @tripleee: Please provide some evidence to back that up.  My company sends about 1 million emails/year, with Return Path reputation monitoring and a very high deliverability rate across all major email providers and ISPs.  I'm basing my statement on that experience.  If "sending hundreds of identical messages which only differ by the To:" were in fact broadly used to detect spam, we would not succeed in what we do.

Comment: @highwingers: See my previous comment to tripleee.  My company sends around 1 million emails/year as outlined in my response.  We have an incredibly high deliverability rate.

Comment: @tripleee: I added references to back up my position regarding bcc

Comment: Your links certainly back the claim that an explicit `BCC:` header is a spammer trick; but the basic technique of putting `To: mailing-list@example.com` and the real recipients in the envelope remains the method used by all mailing list managers I know about (Majordomo and Smartlist are probably too old to count; Listserv, Lyris, Mailman, EOC).  Mailman alone probably delivers 1 million emails a month, I would speculate.

Comment: @tripleee: Modern Lyris does not use *bcc*.  Didn't check the others.  There are issues above and beyond spam e.g. bounce detection.  See ftp://ftp.lyris.com/listmanager/doc/5.0/lm-doc.pdf * other list managers send one message to a list, and use a huge BCC: list to get it out. When someone posts to a mailing list, exactly the same message is sent to every member of the list. The problem with this approach is that when bounces come back, it is very difficult to determine which user bounced it, because every
message was the same.* Presumably other modern list managers have the same issue.

Comment: You can selectively add VERP but it's off by default in Mailman for example.  http://wiki.list.org/display/DOC/So+what+is+this+VERP+stuff  Doing it by default seems very expensive, precisely because it generates much higher loads.  It also depends somewhat on your recipient base, of course; if a majority of your subscribers are on a few big webmail systems, it may make more sense to enable VERP by default (and risk being blocked by the webmail systems in question, because your traffic suddenly got several hundred times bigger).